# I do not understand the compiling order in this sequence of code

Tags: java

I have trouble understanding why at line marked with "////1", the program will return 62 and not 34.
Can anyone explain step by step? I am a beeginer in java and I am struggeling to understand the order of execution.

```
class X {
        public void proc(X p){
            System.out.println(12);
        }
}

class Y extends X{
    public void proc(X p){
        System.out.println(62);
    }
}

class Z extends Y{
    public void proc(Z p){
        System.out.println(34);
    }
}

class Main4{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        X x = new Z();
        Y y = new Z();
        Z z = new Z();
        x.proc(z);////1
    }
}
```

Any help would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: `proc(Z)` **doesn't** override `proc(X)`.

Answer (score 1):

`x.proc(z)` choose from methods in `x` type (which is `X`) in compile time. Only available method is `proc(X)`.

Also keep in mind that `public void proc(Z p)` in `Z` doesn't override `public void proc(X p)`.

Answer (score 1):

You get this result because your `proc` methods do not override each other.

The easiest way to see this is to add an `@Override`-annotation:

```
static class Z extends Y {
    public Z() {
        v += 9;
    }

    @Override
    public void proc(Z p) {
        System.out.println(34);
    }
}
```

This will fail to compile with the error message

> The method proc(Test.Z) of type Test.Z must override or implement a supertype method

It is a good idea to add this annotation whenever you intend to override a method - that way the compiler can check if you actually do.

To fix the error and override the method to get your expected output, you could change the type of the parameter to `X`:

```
static class Z extends Y {
    public Z() {
        v += 9;
    }

    @Override
    public void proc(X p) {
        System.out.println(34);
    }
}
```

Now it compiles again, and yields `34`.

---

What happened in your example is that, instead of overriding, your class `Z` added an overloaded method `void proc(Z p)` *in addition* to the `void proc(X p)` method from `X`. Overload resolution is based on the compile time type, therefore only the method from `X` is available and gets chosen. This method is overridden in `Y`, so that is what is actually executed at runtime.

Therefore, a different way to get your expected result is to leave `X`, `Y` and `Z` unchanged, and change the reference type of `x` to `Z`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Z x = new Z();
    Y y = new Z();
    Z z = new Z();
    x.proc(z);//// 1
    System.out.println(y.getV());
}
```

This version invokes the *overloaded* method in `Z`, because it is the most specific overload for a parameter of type `Z`.